Why I can't save dataset with Jinja variables?
Why I cant save dataset with Jinja variables?
I've edited superset_config.py:
FEATURE_FLAGS = {
        "ALERT_REPORTS": True,
        "ENABLE_TEMPLATE_PROCESSING": True
}

I can run this code in SQL lab:
with ranks as (
  select    *
  from revenue_ranks
  where revenue_rank <= {{ custom_revenue_rank_value }}
)
select date
    , salon_name
    , staff_name
    , revenue_fact
    , revenue_rank as revenue_rnk
from ranks

Parameters for this code:
{"custom_revenue_rank_value": 5}


Dataset with variable:
SELECT arrayJoin([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) AS custom_revenue_rank_value

But I can't save it.
If I try save it without variable and change dataset after saving I still can't use variable.
I still can't use variables.
I add custom_revenue_rank_value to filter and apply filter to table chart.
Code for chart:

Error:

What am I doing wrong?

I've just figure out how to use filter with Jinja variables.
I can get value from filter by {{ filter_values('custom_revenue_rank_value') }}.
But I get array like this: [4].
So I just get value from array with this code:
arrayElement({{ filter_values('custom_revenue_rank_value') }}, 1)

Full code:
   with ranks as (
      select    *
      from revenue_ranks
      where revenue_rank <= arrayElement({{ filter_values('custom_revenue_rank_value') }}, 1)
    )
    select date
        , salon_name
        , staff_name
        , revenue_fact
        , revenue_rank as revenue_rnk
    from ranks

